# What is wrong with my my Python if else statement?

Tags: python

```
PersonsName = input('Enter your name: ')
print('Hello', PersonsName)

AnswerToHowAreYouToday = input('How are you feeling today? Are you doing Good or Bad?')


print('Ok', PersonsName,'So today you are basically feeling', AnswerToHowAreYouToday, '.')


a = "Good"
b = "Bad"
if AnswerToHowAreYouToday: a
print('Good')
else:
    print('Bad')
```

Comment: 1- It's not indented properly 2- `AnswerToHowAreYouToday` is string, not boolean or 3- you don't compare equality with `:`, you do it with `==`. The `:` comes at the end of the `if` statement.

Comment: Don't just paste your code here and ask for help. Please first describe what problems you have encountered and what have you tried yourself to solve the problem.

Comment: If you want print how he is feeling just print `AnswerToHowAreYouToday`. There is no need of `if else` here. If `AnswerToHowAreYouToday` is something other than `"good"` and `"bad"` you would get no output.

Comment: Everybody, thank you for your help. I am sure I will have more questions for you. I will apply my learnings and report back.

Answer (score 4):

Your if else statement indentation is wrong. Generally four whitespaces are used for indentation and is preferred over tabs. Indentation can be ignored in line continuation. But it's a good idea to always indent.

```
PersonsName = input('Enter your name: ')
print('Hello', PersonsName)

AnswerToHowAreYouToday = input('How are you feeling today? Are you doing Good or Bad?')


print('Ok', PersonsName,'So today you are basically feeling', AnswerToHowAreYouToday, '.')


a = "Good"
b = "Bad"
if AnswerToHowAreYouToday == a:
    print('Good')
else:
    print('Bad')
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `if AnswerToHowAreYouToday: a` should be like this `if AnswerToHowAreYouToday == a`. @Santhos have mentioned it but when your code running your output display like this

```
Enter your name: Deepak                                                                                                              
Hello Deepak                                                                                                                         
How are you feeling today? Are you doing Good or Bad?Good                                                                            
Ok Deepak So today you are basically feeling Good .                                                                                  
Good
```

You can see **two Good** printed at last. To avoid these issues you can improved your code like this

```
PersonsName = input('Enter your name: ')
print('Hello', PersonsName)

AnswerToHowAreYouToday = input('How are you feeling today? Are you doing Good or Bad? ')

print('Ok', PersonsName,'So today you are basically feeling ', end = '')

a = "Good"
b = "Bad"
if AnswerToHowAreYouToday == a:
    print('Good.')
else:
    print('Bad.')
```

**Then Output will be:**

```
Enter your name: Deepak                                                                                                              
Hello Deepak                                                                                                                         
How are you feeling today? Are you doing Good or Bad? Good                                                                            
Ok Deepak So today you are basically feeling Good.
```